# Handling http response one by one in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, rxjs

Actually i have 15 http requests which are send to the API. 
All i want to do is to handle responses one by one whithout waiting the end of all the requests (I have a request which can take some minutes to send result).

Service side :

```
    findOneByOne(): Observable<any> {
    const calls = this.getCardsPath().map(el => this.getPromises(el));
    return Observable.forkJoin(calls)
        .map(res => {
            const tab = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                tab.push(this.checkInfoService(res[i].json()));
            }
            return tab;
        });
}


getPromises(str: String): Promise<any> {
    return this.requester.obtain({
        restUrl: "/administration/" + str,
        method: RequestMethod.Get
    })
        .toPromise()
        .then(res => res)
        .catch(err => err);
}
```

Component side :

```
    displayDashboardInfoService() {
    if (this.featuresFlag.getCurrentVersion() !== "1.08" && this.featuresFlag.getCurrentVersion() !== "-1") {
        this.busy = this.dashboardInfoService.findAll()
            .then((res: DashboardInfo[]) => this.findPaths(res))
            .then((res: DashboardInfo[]) => this.loadItems(res))
            .catch((err: any) => {
                if (environment.debugLevel >= 3) console.error(err);
            });
    }
    else {

        this.dashboardInfoService.findOneByOne()
            .subscribe((res) => {
                const tab = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
                    tab.push(res[i][0]);
                }
                this.findPaths(tab);
                this.loadItems(tab);
            });
    }

}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: you should probably use  the `merge` operator instead of using the `forkJoin`. That will generate an event for every request that completes and you can handle them one by one instead of all at once.

Comment: Have a look at `concatMap`

Comment: mergeMap is more useful to flatten some inner observables. In your case however it sounds like you start directly with a list of observables and you want to treat their responses individually. That means 10 initial requests made then 10 responses whenever they end. If you want to have 1 request - 1 response, 1 request - 1 response you can use concatMap as @martin suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to change the `forkJoin` to `merge` so that instead of getting one event when all the requests are done you get an event after each one of them finishes.

If you'd have for example this:

```js
waitForAll() {
  this.values = [];
  this.loadAllAtOnce([100, 200, 300, 400, 3000])
    .subscribe(values => {
      this.values = values;
    });
}

loadAllAtOnce(values: number[]) {
  return forkJoin(
    values.map(x => of (x).pipe(delay(x)))
  ).pipe(
    tap(values => {
      console.log(values);

    })
  );
}
```

It could be rewritten to this:

```js
asTheyCome() {
  this.values = [];
  this.loadAsSoonAsAvailable([100, 200, 300, 400, 3000])
    .subscribe(value => {
      this.values.push(value);
    });
}

loadAsSoonAsAvailable(values: number[]) {
  return merge(
    ...values.map(x => of (x).pipe(delay(x)))
  ).pipe(
    tap(value => console.log(value))
  );
}
```

You can find a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forkjoin-vs-merge).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is example is very helpfull

Comment: I'm glad it is. Let me know if you want one for concatMap or mergeMap as well.

Comment: It actually works! It displays the cards, one after the other ! Thanks ^^

Comment: keep in mind that the order is the one the responses come in, you'll have to do the ordering yourself if you need a specific order.

Comment: Can i ask you a question about how to refresh array dynamicly ?

Comment: @ims16 in a separate question yes. :) I won't get to it for about 3-4 hours, maybe someone else will be able to help you until then.

Comment: Here is the new question if you can help :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988318/update-on-datachange-on-angular-6