# Update on datachange on Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, view

I have an array with 15 responses when the 15 requests ends. I want to update the view when a new response is added to the array without refreshing the page.

```
    loadItem(res: DashboardInfo[]): void {
    this.item.push([]); // ERROR
    this.item.push([]); // WARNING
    this.item.push([]); // INFORMATION
    this.item.push([]); // OK
    let element;
    while ((element = res.pop())) {
        let index: number;
        if (element.level === "ERROR") index = 0;
        else if (element.level === "WARNING") index = 1;
        else if (element.level === "INFORMATION") index = 2;
        else index = 3;
        if (element.path !== undefined) {
            if (this.featuresFlag.visibleFeatures.includes(element.path)) {
                this.item[index].push(element);
                this.item = this.item.slice();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to update the view with? You say you don't want the DOM refreshed. What part of DOM? How are you showing this nested matrix thing?

Comment: @Zlatko I want to update the cards on the dashboard without refreshing the dashboard. I mean, if i had 4 cards and only 3 of them were displayed on the dashboard, when the fourth request ends, i want it to be displayed on the dashboard without refreshing it

Comment: Then it's achievable with trackBy, as the answer below suggests, or OnPush change detection strategy, or a combination of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@pascalpuetz has the right answer. 
Here's a more more specific example though:

If a card would have this interface:

```js
interface Card {
  id: string; // a value that uniquely identifies a card
  type: 'error' | 'success' | 'warning';
  message: string;
  delay: number;
}
```

You could track them by a unique property of the **Card** object like the id.

```js
trackCardsById(index: number, card: Card) {
  return card.id;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let card of cards; trackBy:trackCardsById " class="card" [ngClass]="card.type">
  {{card.message}}
</div>
```

Or you could track them by their position in the list:

```js
trackCardsByIndex(index: number, card: Card) {
  return index;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let card of cards; trackBy:trackCardsByIndex " class="card" [ngClass]="card.type">
  {{card.message}}
</div>
```

You can see a working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cardtrackby-example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @toskv. Actually, it works for the cards which takes some seconds to get the informations that are related to it. But, i have a card which take 1 minute maybe more, and this one is displayed only when i refresh the page. I mean, it's not added dynamicly to the dashboard :/

Comment: it should work the same no matter what the timer is. Maybe something else is happening. Are you sure the request is resolved? I would try debugging the code and trying to see what happens.

Comment: Yuup, the request is resolved when i check the calls in the browser (Code 200 is returned after 1 minute), but it'll never appears dynamicly, i have to refresh the page to see the card. I'll debug to understand what's going on, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the *ngFor trackBy attribute on your template.

```
<div *ngFor="let i of items; trackBy: trackByFn"></div>
```

and on your component.ts

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index; // or item.id
}
```

You can find a good example here: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5

Comment: Trackby is easier to use when it's for 1 item, but here i have a card to return so i don't really know how to handle this

Comment: Your items should be of type "card" or whatever your representational data structure for your card is. TrackBy is then used to identify your card by a certain attribute (e.g. an id)